# Regexp only secondary matches

Tags: php, regex

We have mysql result with strings like:
**Test string article title** *(this string is normal with first uppercase letter)*
**Test String Article Title** *(this string includes uppercase letters in body)*
How we can match string containing uppercase letters (second example string) without matching the first letter (first example string)?

Comment: you mean this `^[A-Z][a-z]*(?:\s[A-Z][a-z]*)+$`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to match all strings that contain upper case letters, but you do not care about the case of the first word, you can use the following regex with `Multiline` option:

```
^\p{L}*\s*(?:\p{Lu}\p{L}*\s*)+$
```

Have a look at [this example](https://regex101.com/r/nV2sC8/1).

It will match "Test String Article Title", and "test String Article Title", but not "Test string article title".

Example code:

```
$re = "/^\\p{L}*\\s*(?:\\p{Lu}\\p{L}*\\s*)+$/m"; 
$str = "Test string article title\nTest String Article Title\ntest String Article Title"; 
preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
```